Scipy sparse array to the power of another numpy array
I have a sparse array that needs to be raised to the power of another array (contains many zeros), but below is a simple example:
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

x1 = np.array([[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]])
x2 = sp.sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1]]))

However, when I use the function below I get the error message "sparse matrix is not square". How can I do this using sparse matrices?
np.power(x2, x1)


Are you asking for each member of the matrix to be raised to a power, or are you asking for the matrix power?

Your second array does not have an implicit 0 values, so does not need to be sparse
In [57]: x1 = np.array([[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]])
    ...: x2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]])

In [58]: np.power(x2,x1)
Out[58]: 
array([[   1,   64, 2187, 6561,  512,    1],
       [   1,   64, 2187, 6561,  512,    1]])

power has raised each element of x2 to the corresponding power in x1.  By broadcasting the result is (2,6)  (i.e.a (2,6) broadcasted with a (6,))
Be careful when using numpy functions on sparse matrices.  It doesn't always work.
If I make a sparse matrix
In [61]: x3 = sparse.csr_matrix(x2)

In [62]: x3
Out[62]: 
<2x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [63]: np.power(x3,x1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[63], line 1
----> 1 np.power(x3,x1)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_base.py:721, in spmatrix.__pow__(self, other)
    719 M, N = self.shape[0], self.shape[1]
    720 if M != N:
--> 721     raise TypeError('matrix is not square')
    723 if isintlike(other):
    724     other = int(other)

TypeError: matrix is not square

Here we see that np.power has delegated the task to the __pow__ method of the sparse matrix, same as if we wrote x3**x1.
If I make a small square matrix, I find that ** is the same as matrix multiplication.  That's not repeated elementwise multiplication.
In [74]: M=sparse.csr_matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [75]: (M**3).A
Out[75]: 
array([[ 37,  54],
       [ 81, 118]], dtype=int32)
In [76]: (M*M*M).A
Out[76]: 
array([[ 37,  54],
       [ 81, 118]], dtype=int32)

If we use the newer csr_array, we do get elementwise multiplication - but only by scalars:
In [87]: M=sparse.csr_array([[1,2],[3,4]])    
In [88]: (M**3).A
C:\Users\14256\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_base.py:752: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Please use `.todense()` instead
  warn(np.VisibleDeprecationWarning(
Out[88]: 
array([[ 1,  8],
       [27, 64]], dtype=int32)

In [89]: (M*M*M).A
C:\Users\14256\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_base.py:752: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Please use `.todense()` instead
  warn(np.VisibleDeprecationWarning(
Out[89]: 
array([[ 1,  8],
       [27, 64]], dtype=int32)

In [94]: (sparse.csr_array(x2)**3).A
C:\Users\14256\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_base.py:752: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Please use `.todense()` instead
  warn(np.VisibleDeprecationWarning(
Out[94]: 
array([[ 1,  8, 27, 27,  8,  1],
       [ 1,  8, 27, 27,  8,  1]], dtype=int32)


Thanks. I have a large sparse matrix. Does your answer imply that in that case I cannot do the power of an sparse array of size (N,J) to the power of a dense array of size (N,1)?

I also added a couple of zeros in x2 to make clear that I have a sparse matrix.

Adding a few zeros doesn't make a difference.  You still need to define what you really want with power.  Matrix power of a square matrix makes some sense.  Elementwise power just performes the power operation on the individual nonzero terms.  Sparse matrices/arrays don't implement broadcasting.  Your x2.__pow__ and x2.power implement the matrix and elementwise powers respectively.  Look at the source code yourself.
